# C++ Usage of switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
int i = 10;

switch( i )
{
    case 1:
        // do sth1
        break;

    case 2:
        // do sth2
        break;

    case 3:
        // do sth3
        break;

    default:
        // do sth default
        break;
}
```

**Question 1**>  When the switch statement executes, do we jump directly to the right case statement or do we search from top to bottom?

*Answer*:  Directly jump to the right case statement.

**Question 2**> Should we use a break statement after the default statement?

*Answer*:  Depends. If the default statement is the last case statement, then using break is NOT necessary.

Did I get the answers right in the above questions?

Comment: The `default` statement should *always* be the last case.

Comment: Careful with always.  I've had one case where I made it first in a duff's device type construct.

Comment: I'd like to add that while using fall through is a valid and effective technique, other people who might work on the code with you may see it as a 'bug', and want to put a break statement in.  Forgetting to put a break in is a rather common mistake, so it's understandable.  To avoid that, it helps to leave a comment saying the fallthrough was intentional.

Comment: @Clairvoire: I usually add a `//nobrake` comment whenever I fall through intentionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: Depends on the compiler.  C++ standard does not require that a jump table be set up.

In many cases, especially with small number of sparse cases, GCC, MSVC and other compilers will do clause-by-clause check (as if it were an if statement).  To give an example, suppose your cases were 1, 15, and 1000000.  It would not be efficient code-wise to do a direct jump.

gcc has the option `-fno-jump-tables` to force it to build the equivalent if-else list.

Question 2: The break statement is not required for the last clause.  It should be omitted if execution should flow down.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for answer two, except I would add that a break is necessary after the default statement if it's the last case *or* its not and you don't  want it to fall through. But that's just a nitpick.

The answer to question one depends on if optimisations are enabled and how smart your compiler is. If optimisations are low or disabled (or your compiler is just old and/or not very sophisticated) it will do a search from top to bottom skipping over the default case (thanks q0987). If optimisations are enabled and the compiler decides to do it, it will be optimised into a jump table, in which case it will jump directly to the correct case.

Comment: If the optimization is disabled and assume what you said is right, then the code will not be valid if I put default statement in front of all cases. While if I remember correctly, C++ doesn't require to put default in a specific location.

Comment: "if it's the last case and you don't want it to fall through. But that's just a nitpick."... fall through **to where**? It's the last case!

Answer (score 0):

> **Question 1>** When the switch statement executes, do we jump directly to the right
>   case statement or do we search from top to bottom?

I don't think there is any mention about this implementation detail in the standard. However, your answer is correct for that.

> **Question 2>** Should we use a break statement after the default statement?

Yes, it depends on the requirement. Sometime you may not need it at all. Consider the situation, where you want to do something for `default:` case and little lesser thing for say `case 1:`. For example,

```
switch(i)
{
  default: foo();
  case 1:  bar();
           break;
  case 2:  abc();
           break;
  case 3:  xyz();
           break;
}
```